# nvd3 prevent repeated values on y axis

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

My chart repeats the values on the y axis. Is there a way I can only have 1,2,3 but nothing between (e.g the problem I have is shown on the chart below on the y axis):

[image]

The code im using is something like this:

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
    var chart = nv.models.multiBarChart();

    chart.xAxis
        .tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d)) });

    chart.yAxis
        .tickFormat(d3.format(',.1f'));

    d3.select('#errorsFiredByDate')
        .datum([{values: output, key: "Count by date"}])
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .call(chart);

        nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

    return chart;
});
```

Comment: Not sure what's going on there -- your number format specifies that there should be one value after the decimal point (`',.1f'`). Have you tried changing that format specifier and see what happens?

Comment: I set it to the above screenshot uses `0f`, I tried earlier with `,.1f` which is in the code sample, it puts decimal places on but i'd prefer not to have the 0.5 on. I thought using `0f` would fix it but it still puts on two `1`s

Comment: Ah ok, so you want to control the number of ticks/the actual ticks themselves?

Comment: Exactly! For the chart above it would be better to just have 1 2 & 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options to control the ticks in a D3 axis. You can specify the number of ticks explicitly using [`.ticks()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-ticks), but this is more of a hint to the layout that may be disregarded. If you want to be absolutely sure about the ticks, use [`.tickValues()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-tickValues) to set the tick values explicitly.

In your case, this would look something like this.

```
chart.yAxis.tickValues(d3.range(chart.yAxis.scale().domain()[0], chart.yAxis.scale().domain()[1]);
```

Other methods for figuring out the range may be more suitable, depending on your concrete application.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem and I did this in chart options to fix

```
    yAxis: {
      tickFormat: function(d){
        if ( (d * 10) % 10 === 0 ) {
          return d3.format('.0f')(d);
        }
        else {
          return '';
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A late reply , but might be useful to others. I use a workaround to eliminate duplicate ticks, by maintaining an array of already applied ticks & d3's multi format specifier.

```
uniqueTicks = [];
xTickFormat = d3.time.format.multi([
                                    ["%Y", function (d) {
                                        if (uniqueTicks.indexOf(d.getFullYear()) === -1) {
                                            uniqueTicks.push(d.getFullYear());
                                            return true;
                                        } else {
                                            return false;
                                        }                                        
                                    }],
                                    ["", function () {
                                        return true;
                                    }]
                                ]);

d3.svg.axis().tickFormat(xTickFormat );
```

This trick can be tweaked for any other type of tick format.